# DB2 : Eleminating Null while grouping data

Tags: sql, db2

I have a dataset like below

```
Col1       Col2        Col3        Col4
PK_Col1    V_Col2      Null        Null
PK_Col1    Null        V_Col3      Null
PK_Col1    Null        Null        V_Col4
PK_Col1    Null        V_Col31     Null
PK_Col1    Null        V_Col32     Null
PK_Col2    Null        Null        Null
PK_Col3    V_Col23     Null        Null
```

I want to the output like below

```
Col1       Col2        Col3        Col4
PK_Col1    V_Col2      V_Col3      V_Col4
PK_Col1    V_Col2      V_Col31     V_Col4
PK_Col1    V_Col2      V_Col32     V_Col4
PK_Col2    Null        Null        Null
PK_Col3    V_Col23     Null        Null
```

How this can be achieved avoiding self join. I am working in DB2 environment and the actual table is huge in size, so really want to avoid any self join.

Answer (score 2):

Such an algorithm requires explicit ordering inside each `Col1` group. The `ROW_NUMBER` function is used here for that, because I don't see any other method for ordering.

```
WITH T (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) AS
(
VALUES
  ('PK_Col1', 'V_Col2 ',  Null    ,  Null   )
, ('PK_Col1',  Null    , 'V_Col3 ',  Null   )
, ('PK_Col1',  Null    ,  Null    , 'V_Col4')
, ('PK_Col1',  Null    , 'V_Col31',  Null   )
, ('PK_Col1',  Null    , 'V_Col32',  Null   )
, ('PK_Col2',  Null    ,  Null    ,  Null   )
, ('PK_Col3', 'V_Col23',  Null    ,  Null   )
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  Col1
--, RN_, Col2, Col3, Col4
, COALESCE 
  (
    Col2
  , LEAD (Col2, 1, NULL::CHAR, 'IGNORE NULLS') OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY RN_)
  , LAG  (Col2, 1, NULL::CHAR, 'IGNORE NULLS') OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY RN_)
  ) AS Col2_
, COALESCE 
  (
    Col3
  , LEAD (Col3, 1, NULL::CHAR, 'IGNORE NULLS') OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY RN_)
  , LAG  (Col3, 1, NULL::CHAR, 'IGNORE NULLS') OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY RN_)
  ) AS Col3_
, COALESCE 
  (
    Col4
  , LEAD (Col4, 1, NULL::CHAR, 'IGNORE NULLS') OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY RN_)
  , LAG  (Col4, 1, NULL::CHAR, 'IGNORE NULLS') OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY RN_)
  ) AS Col4_
FROM 
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER () AS RN_
FROM T
)
ORDER BY Col1
```

| COL1 | COL2_ | COL3_ | COL4_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PK_Col1 | V_Col2 | V_Col3 | V_Col4 |
| PK_Col1 | V_Col2 | V_Col31 | V_Col4 |
| PK_Col1 | V_Col2 | V_Col32 | V_Col4 |
| PK_Col2 |  |  |  |
| PK_Col3 | V_Col23 |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `UNION` clause :

```
select Col1, max(Col2), max(Col3), max(Col4)
from mytable
group by Col1
union
select Col1, min(Col2), min(Col3), min(Col4)
from mytable
group by Col1
order by Col1
```

Comment: Sorry, my dummy example wasn't great. You solution will not work if we have more that 2 not null values in Col3